# React: chartjs nagative area different color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I using chartjs and react-chartjs-2 line chart for positive and negative value, for positive value I want the filled area is green, and negative area is red.

https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/recursing-drake-v2rsj7

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Filler,
  Legend,
} from "chart.js";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import faker from "faker";

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Filler,
  Legend,
);

export const options = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
      position: "top" as const,
    },
    title: {
      display: false,
      text: "Chart.js Line Chart",
    },
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      grid: {
        display: false, // Hides X-axis grid lines
      },
      ticks: {
        display: false, // Hides X-axis labels
      },
      border: {
        display: false, // Hides X-axis border line
      },
    },
    y: {
      grid: {
        display: false, // Hides Y-axis grid lines
      },
      ticks: {
        display: false, // Hides Y-axis labels
      },
      border: {
        display: false, // Hides X-axis border line
      },
    },
  },
};

const generateChartData = () => {
  const values = [3000, 4000, -1000, -2000, 2000, 3000, 5000];
  const backgroundColors = values.map((val) =>
    val >= 0 ? "rgba(50, 183, 73, 0.2)" : "rgba(212, 68, 90, 0.2)",
  );

  return {
    labels: [
      "Page A",
      "Page B",
      "Page C",
      "Page D",
      "Page E",
      "Page F",
      "Page G",
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Dataset 1",
        data: values,
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: backgroundColors,
        borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
        tension: 0.4,
      },
    ],
  };
};
export function App() {
  const data = generateChartData();
  return <Line options={options} data={data} />;
}
```

This is current result
[image]

This is expected result

[image]

Comment: You could use `fill` with `target`, `above` and `below`, see [example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/area.html#example-with-multiple-colors)

Comment: @kikon can the border do the same ? positive green, negative red

Comment: No, that needs something more complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update2**

I've just realized that there is a much simpler and more effective solution for the line color, and that is to set a vertical gradient for the whole height of plot, with a change of color at the y=0 height.

Unlike the solution in the previous update, it doesn't need a supplemental `update` and works OK even during animation. That means that it also works OK with chart data updates. Here it is:

```js
const values = [3000, 2000, -1000, -6000, 1000, 3000, 5000];

const lineColorPlus = "rgba(50, 183, 73, 0.75)",
    lineColorMinus = "rgba(212, 68, 90, 0.75)";
const data = {
    labels: [
        "Page A",
        "Page B",
        "Page C",
        "Page D",
        "Page E",
        "Page F",
        "Page G",
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: values,
            tension: 0.4,
            segment: {
                borderWidth: 4,
                borderColor: function({p0DataIndex, p1DataIndex, datasetIndex, chart}){
                    const y0 = data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[p0DataIndex],
                        y1 = data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[p1DataIndex];
                    if(y0 >= 0 && y1 >= 0){
                        return lineColorPlus;
                    }
                    if(y0 <= 0 && y1 <= 0){
                        return lineColorMinus;
                    }
                    const yScale = chart.getDatasetMeta(datasetIndex).yScale,
                        ygZero = yScale.getPixelForValue(0),
                        ygMax = yScale.getPixelForValue(yScale.max),
                        ygMin = yScale.getPixelForValue(yScale.min);

                    const fracGradient = (ygZero - ygMin)/(ygMax - ygMin);
                    const ctx = chart.ctx;
                    const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, ygMin, 0, ygMax);

                    gradient.addColorStop(0, lineColorMinus);
                    gradient.addColorStop(fracGradient, lineColorMinus);
                    gradient.addColorStop(fracGradient, lineColorPlus);
                    gradient.addColorStop(1, lineColorPlus);

                    return gradient;
                },
            },
            pointRadius: 5,
            fill: {
                target: 'origin',
                above: "rgba(50, 183, 73, 0.5)",
                below: "rgba(212, 68, 90, 0.5)"
            }
        }
    ]
};

const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
    },
};

const chart = new Chart(document.querySelector('#chart1'), config);
const interval = setInterval(
    ()=> {
        values.forEach(
            (value, i) => {values[i] = value + Math.round(Math.random() * 4 - 2) * 1000}
        );
        chart.update();
    },
    5000
);
const buttonStop = document.querySelector('#stop');
buttonStop.onclick = () => {clearInterval(interval); buttonStop.disabled = true;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-ZwR1/gSZM3ai6vCdI+LVF1zSq/5HznD3ZSTk7kajkaj4D292NLuduDCO1c/NT8Id+jE58KYLKT7hXnbtryGmMg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div style="min-height: 80vh">
    <canvas id="chart1">
    </canvas>
</div>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

---

**Original post**

To set the fill according to color, one may use the `fill` property
with `target`, `above` and `below`, as per [the documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/area.html#example-with-multiple-colors).

Setting the colors for the line is more complicated, for as far as I know,
there is no option to do that depending on the value. So one has to
compute the colors for each segment, which involves some interpolation
for those segments that intersect `y` axis.

Even so, this is linear interpolation, and if high values are used for `tension`
and the points are sparse (large intervals), the difference between this and
the actual cubic curve might become visible at the intersections.

Here's a possible implementation:, based on your example:

```js
const values = [3000, 4000, -1000, -2000, 2000, 3000, 5000];

const lineColorPlus = "rgba(50, 183, 73, 0.75)",
    lineColorMinus = "rgba(212, 68, 90, 0.75)";
const data = {
    labels: [
        "Page A",
        "Page B",
        "Page C",
        "Page D",
        "Page E",
        "Page F",
        "Page G",
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: values,
            tension: 0.4,
            segment: {
                borderWidth: 4,
                borderColor: function(dataCtx){
                    const {p0, p1, p0DataIndex, p1DataIndex, datasetIndex, chart} = dataCtx;
                    const y0 = data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[p0DataIndex],
                        y1 = data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[p1DataIndex];
                    if(y0 >= 0 && y1 >= 0){
                        return lineColorPlus;
                    }
                    if(y0 <= 0 && y1 <= 0){
                        return lineColorMinus;
                    }

                    const frac = Math.abs(y0 / (y0 - y1));
                    const xg0 = p0.$animations?.x?._to || p0.x,
                        yg0 = p0.$animations?.y?._to || p0.y,
                        xg1 = p1.$animations?.x?._to || p1.x,
                        yg1 = p1.$animations?.y?._to || p1.y;
                    const ctx = chart.ctx;
                    const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(xg0, yg0, xg1, yg1);
                    const [col1, col2] = (y0 <= 0) ? [lineColorMinus, lineColorPlus] : [lineColorPlus, lineColorMinus] ;
                    gradient.addColorStop(0, col1);
                    gradient.addColorStop(frac, col1);
                    gradient.addColorStop(frac, col2);
                    gradient.addColorStop(1, col2);

                    return gradient;
                },
            },
            pointRadius: 0,
            fill: {
                target: 'origin',
                above: "rgba(50, 183, 73, 0.5)",
                below: "rgba(212, 68, 90, 0.5)"
            }
        }
    ]
};

const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
    },
};

new Chart(document.querySelector('#chart1'), config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-ZwR1/gSZM3ai6vCdI+LVF1zSq/5HznD3ZSTk7kajkaj4D292NLuduDCO1c/NT8Id+jE58KYLKT7hXnbtryGmMg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div style="min-height: 60vh">
    <canvas id="chart1">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

---

**Update**

I made a more complicated variant that takes into account the bezier curve used with `tension` to optimize the computation of the
gradient cutoff. One has to take into account the fact that the final Bezier coefficients are only computed after the initial animation has completed, so one has to either disable animation or to add an `chart.update('none')` in the `animation.onComplete` handler, as it is shown in the example below.

```js
const _bezierInterpolation = Chart.helpers._bezierInterpolation; // note: different access for modules
const values = [3000, 2000, -1000, -6000, 1000, 3000, 5000];

const NMaxOptimization = 20, // break optimization loop after NMaxOptimization
    zeroFraction = 1e-4; // break optimization loop if the bezier absolute value < zeroFraction * yAxisRange

const lineColorPlus = "rgba(50, 183, 73, 0.75)",
    lineColorMinus = "rgba(212, 68, 90, 0.75)";
const data = {
    labels: [
        "Page A",
        "Page B",
        "Page C",
        "Page D",
        "Page E",
        "Page F",
        "Page G",
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: values,
            tension: 0.8,
            segment: {
                borderWidth: 4,
                borderColor: function({p0, p1, p0DataIndex, p1DataIndex, datasetIndex, chart}){
                    const y0 = data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[p0DataIndex],
                        y1 = data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[p1DataIndex];
                    if(y0 >= 0 && y1 >= 0){
                        return lineColorPlus;
                    }
                    if(y0 <= 0 && y1 <= 0){
                        return lineColorMinus;
                    }

                    const xg0 = p0.$animations?.x?._to || p0.x,
                        yg0 = p0.$animations?.y?._to || p0.y,
                        xg1 = p1.$animations?.x?._to || p1.x,
                        yg1 = p1.$animations?.y?._to || p1.y;
                    const optimize = !(p0.$animations?.x?._active || p0.$animations?.y?._active);
                    // don't optimize on active animation, bezier coeffs are not final, nor useful now
                    let frac = Math.abs(y0 / (y0 - y1));
                    let xgZero = xg0 + (xg1 - xg0) * frac,
                        ygZero = yg0 + (yg1 - yg0) * frac;

                    if(optimize && (chart.options.elements.line.tension || data.datasets[datasetIndex].tension)){
                        const p0Final = {...p0, x: xg0, y: yg0},
                            p1Final = {...p1, x: xg1, y: yg1};
                        const yScale = chart.getDatasetMeta(datasetIndex).yScale;
                        let {y: ygFrac} = _bezierInterpolation(p0Final, p1Final, frac);

                        let fracLeft = 0;
                        let fracRight = 1;
                        let ygLeft = yg0;
                        let ygRight = yg1;

                        let yForLeft = yScale.getValueForPixel(ygLeft);
                        let yForFrac = yScale.getValueForPixel(ygFrac);
                        let yForRight = yScale.getValueForPixel(ygRight);
                        const dy = yScale.max - yScale.min;
                        for(let kOpt = 0; kOpt < NMaxOptimization; kOpt++){
                            if(yForFrac * yForLeft <= 0){
                                fracRight = frac;
                                ygRight = ygFrac;
                                yForRight = yForFrac;
                            }
                            else{
                                fracLeft = frac;
                                ygLeft = ygFrac;
                                yForLeft = yForFrac;
                            }

                            frac = (fracRight + fracLeft) / 2;
                            ({x: xgFrac, y: ygFrac} = _bezierInterpolation(p0Final, p1Final, frac));
                            yForFrac = yScale.getValueForPixel(ygFrac);
                            if(Math.abs(yForFrac) < zeroFraction * dy){
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        // intersection
                        xgZero = xgFrac;
                        ygZero = ygFrac;
                    }

                    const ctx = chart.ctx;
                    let fracGradient = (xgZero - xg0)/(xg1 - xg0);
                    const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(xg0, ygZero, xg1, ygZero);

                    const [colLeft, colRight] = (y0 <= 0) ? [lineColorMinus, lineColorPlus] : [lineColorPlus, lineColorMinus] ;

                    gradient.addColorStop(0, colLeft);
                    gradient.addColorStop(fracGradient, colLeft);
                    gradient.addColorStop(fracGradient, colRight);
                    gradient.addColorStop(1, colRight);

                    return gradient;
                },
            },
            pointRadius: 5,
            fill: {
                target: 'origin',
                above: "rgba(50, 183, 73, 0.5)",
                below: "rgba(212, 68, 90, 0.5)"
            }
        }
    ]
};

const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        animation:{
            onComplete({chart, initial}){
                if(initial){
                    chart.update('none');
                }
            }
        },

        responsive: true,
    },
};

new Chart(document.querySelector('#chart1'), config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-ZwR1/gSZM3ai6vCdI+LVF1zSq/5HznD3ZSTk7kajkaj4D292NLuduDCO1c/NT8Id+jE58KYLKT7hXnbtryGmMg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div style="min-height: 60vh">
    <canvas id="chart1">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, what if the values is dynamic array of positive and negative, I try put other combination, however the border color run away

Comment: @FeelRightz If animation is enabled, you have to make sure that after the animation is completed, you call `chart.update('none')` to adjust the color boundaries. [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/rej9t0cd/) an example (where I added the condition `numSteps > 100` to the `onComplete` handler). If you can add an example of the way in which you update the chart, I can try to find the best way to do it for that case.

Comment: @FeelRightz please check out the latest update (the first code snippet) - there's a much better solution for the line color, that works with animation and  doesn't require an additional `update`